# Spark Streaming: Foreach writing not being initiated in case of large amount of data

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which read the data from kafka topics. Trying to write the incoming data to the database. Thus implementing mysql sink. Before doing I wrote a Simple sink to test out the flow.

It works fine in my local but when I run it in the dev environment, it throws `SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult`.

I believe the reason could be that the dev environment has much more data coming in from the kafka topics.

```
Dataset<Row> stream = sparkSession.readStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServersString)
          .option("subscribe", topic)
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
          .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
//          .option("kafkaConsumer.pollTimeoutMs", "1000")
          .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000)
          .load();

 stream.writeStream().foreach(sink).start();
```

> In dev environment stream prints fine on the console. **console.stream.writeStream().format("console").start();**

**SimpleSink:**

```
public class SimpleSink extends ForeachWriter<Row> {

    public SimpleSink() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean open(long partitionId, long version) {
        System.out.println(">>>");
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void process(Row row) {
        System.out.println("comes here");
        //System.out.println(row.mkString(","));
    }

    @Override
    public void close(Throwable errorOrNull) {
    }

}
```

Because this code works fine in my laptop it means that code is fine. But I have no idea why in higher env Sink in not getting called.

Is there a way to control amount of data going into sink? Not sure if this is the issue but that is my theory.

Comment: And if you search you'll find dozens of other threads explaining why printing from executor cannot work in distributed mode.

Comment: @user6910411 Gotcha. Is there a way to know if data is hitting the sink? I am hesitant to directly write it to the database.

Comment: The details will depend on the cluster manger. For example with standalone cluster  (`spark://...`) the simplest way is to navigate to cluster master, find a link to specific worker, and check it's stdout (logs column). In general you should capture stdout and redirect to some form of aggregator.